# How to dump outputs of all functions called at runtime?

Tags: c++, trace

As usual, I have some code chain starting at the main method. Is there any elegant coding pattern, with which I could easily dump the outputs of all methods ever being called at runtime? I have one idea:

a) Copy the source code into an auxiliary aux:: namespace. For each method in aux:: run its copy of the code from the original:: namespace and after that dump its expected output).

Example pseudo-code:

```
// Source code at some repository
namespace original {
  int B(int input){
    output = input + 5;
    return output;
  }
  int A(int input){
    int output = methodB(input);
    output--;
    return output;
  }
}

// Create auxiliary repo
namespace aux{
  int B(int input){
    output = input + 5;
    // No other dependencies so only dump B output here
    dump(output);
    return output;
  }
  int A(int input){
    int output = methodB(input); // would call aux::methodB
    output--;
    // Dump output of A
    dump(output);
    return output;
  }
}

int main() {
  // Normally I would run original::A() but now I am dumping
  aux:A();
  return 0;
}
```

This would work, but I would need to replace source content everytime the code in original:: changes. I'd like to device something nicer like reusing the definitions in original:: without copying into aux:: but I am kind of stuck there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you tag the question with the language you're using? There are tools to trace program execution, but they usually have a particular purpose such as profiling or debugging. What are you going to use this for?

Comment: C++, I updated the tags. I want to export intermediate results during runtime with json or any other format into the same file for example.

Comment: For what purpose? For example, if it's to find performance bottlenecks you'd use a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)).

Comment: No, the purpose is only that one for now, just generating a file that includes the outputs of all functions from a specific run. One can see it as a ground truth generation process against which the code will be tested afterwards

Comment: If you mean "tested" as in "ensure it still works", a huge stack dump can only tell you its working in *exactly* the same way. That isn't particularly useful, why test the code unless you changed it? Instead, you want to [test that it gives the same results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks). There is a thing called [Design By Contract](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=c%2B%2B+design+by+contract&ia=web) where you test your program's requirements within the code. Either way, dtrace will get you stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of existing tools to do this in C++ without modifying your code. Instead, tools can inject themselves into running code. Which you use depends on your purpose.

[dtrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) is a fairly generic tool to report on function calls in a running process. See [Is it possible to probe the entry in a C++ class using Dtrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223843/is-it-possible-to-probe-the-entry-in-a-c-class-using-dtrace) for an example.

If your intent is to find a performance bottleneck, use a [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). There are many out there, one is [Orbit](https://orbitprofiler.com/).

Finally, some IDEs will have this functionality built in. [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/profiling-tools.html), and [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019) all have tools to analyze your code while it runs.

Answer (score -1):

You may use a global variable as a kind of flag. Incorporate this global flag in all of your functions to switch to the aux-mode.

Like so:

```
bool aux_switch = false;
//bool aux_switch = true;

namespace original
{
  int B(int input){
    output = input + 5;
    if(aux_switch) dump(output);
    return output;
  }
  int A(int input){
    int output = methodB(input);
    output--;
    if(aux_switch) dump(output);
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to keep original:: and aux:: loosely coupled, I do not want to include dumping capabilities in the original source code

Comment: Then just write a script which copies all your data and does the needed changes. You may use comments in your source code to tell your scripts some extra commands, like a custom preprocessor. BTW you should answer the question "What are you going to use this for?".